# just before release - how to check memory usage?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management

Our app is good to go and everything seems to work just fine. We have tried to manage the memory as much as we can and we have no crashes at all.

Now before release, I want to check if there are leaks, or some problems that may cause my app to be rejected by Apple.

What's Apple's policy on memory leaks? Are even small ones not allowed? If some are allowed, then what's the limit?

What software/tool should I use to check memory management/leaks, to be sure that if it gives me good results, my app will be approved by Apple, if simply not crashing is not enough?

Is there a guide about one of this tools ?

Is checking my app in all iOS versions in the iOS Simulator enough? I have only 1 iPhone 4 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do:

- Run "Analyze" (MenuBar -> Product -> Analyze or SHIFT+CMD+B)
  This checks your code for possible leaks and dead stores
- Run "Profile" (MenuBar -> Product -> Profile or SHIFT+I) 
  This runs Instruments which allows you to track your allocations and possible leaks at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a specific policy about leaks - but a program that leak will crash - and Apple do reject apps due to crashes.

Otherwise I do agree with MatzeLoCal - run Analyze, and fix everything - and run a lot of profiling if you suspect there to be any issues.

Comment: "a program that leak will crash" - that's not strictly true. If I leak just 1 `NSString` I very much doubt my app will crash.

Comment: Should be "a program that leaks more will crash"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to running Analyze...

There is a tool in Xcode called Instruments that allows you to search specifically for memory leaks in your application. Choose the Leaks option when prompted when you open Instruments and then mess around in your app while recording to see any memory leaks that may be hiding in your app.

Here is the official Apple documentation for using Instruments: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/FindingLeakedMemory.html